# how to delete value from 2 database table at a time using laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have  2 tables 1. Album.(id,albumname,galimg_id)

```
id  albumname   galimg_id   

1   home    home/a6.jpg     
2   school  school/a8.jpg   
4   staff   staff/joseph povathil1.jpg  
5   students students/a9.jpg    
32  games   games/a5.jpg 
33  onam    onam/a1.jpg
```

2.galleries (id,galname,galimg,album_id)
id   galname      galimg      album_id

1     play         home/a1.jpg      1
2      a6           home/a6.jpg     1
3     school       school/sli1.JPG   2
4     display      school/sli2.jpg     2 
6     archbishop   staff/archbi.jpg    4
7      hm          staff/headmaster.jpg  4
9     a5             school/a5.jpg       2

Im trying to delete home(from Album table)id is 1 and at a time delete home/a6.jpg(from galleries table)id is 2 and album_id is 1.
 but not work. 
how to delete value from 2 database  table at a time using laravel 4

Comment: my controller.php code is                                                         `$galleries= ForumGallery::find($id);
  File::delete('img/Albums/'.$galleries->galimg);
  if(!is_null($galleries))
  {$galleries->delete();
  }$album = Input::get('f11');
   var_dump(Input::get('f11'));
   $albums = ForumAlbum::where('galimg_id', $album)->first();          if(!is_null($albums))
  {$albums->delete();
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
//find gallery id from table
$galleries = ForumGallery::find($id);

//find the album id of gallery entry above
$albums = ForumAlbum::find($galleries->album_id);

//if above queries have results
if ((!is_null($galleries)) && (!is_null($albums))){

    //EDIT
    $albums->galimg_id = ''; //remove galimg_id in ForumAlbum
    $albums->save();  //save the new entry

    $galleries->galimg = ''; //remove galimg in ForumGallery
    $galleries->save();  //save the new entry

    //finally delete the file itself
    File::delete('img/Albums/'.$galleries->galimg);
}
```

Comment: its working...... but i want ForumAlbum only delete galimd_id field.not fully..and FroumGallery table row fully (that ok with this code),but also album table row fully deleted..